# Upload html file and show the html file preview in thymeleaf before uploading

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, thymeleaf

I am developing a spring boot project which uses Thymeleaf as the front end. I am giving the user an option to upload a html(plain html) file and the requirement is also to show the preview of html file before uploading. I could see in the internet there are option to preview an image but i cannot find some example for html file preview. Can someone please help me achieve this ?

```
<div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
                <h2>Upload Email Template</h2>
                <p th:text="${message}" th:if="${message ne null}" class="alert alert-primary"></p>
                <form method="post" th:action="@{/upload}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
                </form>
              </div>
```

controller

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

        // check if file is empty
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload.");
            return "redirect:/";
        }

        // normalize the file path
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

        // save the file on the local file system
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOAD_DIR + fileName);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            log.info("file upload successful" +path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return success response
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "You successfully uploaded " + fileName + '!');


        return "redirect:/monthlyTransactions";
    }
```

Comment: If you need to preview the HTML before uploading, this must be done with client technology HTML+javascript. This task has nothing to do with "Thymeleaf", "Java", and "Spring-mvc". Your question's tags are incorrect except "HTML". I would advise you to change the tags, show what did you tried already with JavaScript, and remove the controller part as it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You have mentioned a lot of examples to preview an image with JavaScript/JQuery. You should take example's code and from [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) get the content as [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) and serve it into new window. This is the plan, just try to work on it, instead of asking ready solution. If you would have some specific questions, post the code and somebody will help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above using like below

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="file" onchange="preview()">
    <div class="frame" ></div>
    <div id="frame" src="" width="100px" height="100px"/>
  </form>




   function preview() {
frame.src=URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
$('div.frame').load(frame.src);
  }


 div.frame{
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:solid #000 1px;
 }
```